# create a generic method that sorts List<T> collections

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda

What I used to do is create a case switch that sorts my LINQ in this format:

```
List<products> productList = GetAllLists();

switch (sortBy)
{
  case "name":
     return productsList.OrderBy(pl => pl.Name);
  case "date":
     return productsList.OrderBy(pl => pl.DateCreate);
}
```

which, in the long run, becomes cumbersome.

I wanted to have a generic method that you simply use to sort out List collections like these and will help you toggle which property to sort by.. something like this:

```
return SortListCollection(productsList, Name);
```

Comment: How is what you're asking here different from what `OrderBy` already provides? Is it that you want to be able to pass a string instead of a `Func<T, TResult>`?

Comment: Hi dan, well probably close to that, i guess.

Comment: Passing a `Func<T,R>` directly, as Dan mentions, would be fast and would allow compile-time checking. Using a string will be slow(er) and will make runtime errors more likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
private List<T> SortList<T>(List<T> collection, SortOrder order, string propertyName) where T : class
        {
            if (order == SortOrder.Descending)
            {
                return collection.OrderByDescending(cc => cc.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(cc, null)).ToList();
            }

            return collection.OrderBy(cc => cc.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(cc, null)).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: This method will have terrible performance. There is a much faster way. Give me a little time and I will post soon.

Comment: just add caching of PropertyInfo (cc.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)) and you will be fine.

Comment: ok alex, i think im settled with the answer. Thanks to all of you who helped!

Comment: Moreover, this is terribly brittle. As soon as you change the name of a property your code will get runtime exceptions and you won't be told about it at compile-time (could possibly be mitigated by having a rule that says only to send properties that you got via the `nameof()` construct)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use reflection for this, you can do it using expression trees, which will be much faster. [Here's a blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2008/12/11/dynamic-sorting-with-linq.aspx) that describes the process, but a cut'n'paste sample is:

```
public static IQueryable<T> SortBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, String.Empty);
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(property, parameter);

    var methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy",
        new Type[] { source.ElementType, property.Type },
        source.Expression, Expression.Quote(lambda));

    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(methodCallExpression);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you *need* to be able to pass in strings? Passing in a `Func<T,TResult>` delegate will be fast, flexible, and allow runtime checking; passing in a `string` won't be.

You could even have a bunch of predefined delegates ready-to-go:

```
var sortedByName = productList.OrderBy(NameSelector);
var sortedByDate = productList.OrderBy(DateCreatedSelector);
var sortedByCustom = productList.OrderBy(p => p.SomeOtherProperty);

// ...

// predefined delegates
public static readonly Func<Product, string> NameSelector = p => p.Name;

public static readonly Func<Product, DateTime> DateCreatedSelector =
                                                     p => p.DateCreated;
```

And, of course, you could wrap it all up in your own method if you wanted to, but that method would be a superfluous one-liner just wrapping the `OrderBy` call.

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection to build a comparer class that can compare by property name. Then instantiate this class and pass it's compare function to `List.Sort`